# DC Fan circuit with MOSFET control of ground

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

I'm looking [at the schematic](https://github.com/Duet3D/Duet-2-Hardware) for the Duet 2, a 3D printer mainboard.

This particular block controls a small DC fan for part cooling (same block also used for the extruder cooling).

`V_FAN` is selectable, can be 5V or 12V based on a jumper set elsewhere.

I assume `FAN0-` is the ground pin for FAN 0.

`FAN0` comes from the MCU and is a line-level pin, presumably 3.3V or 5V.

I don't understand the diode circled in 1 nor the resistors in 2. The specific question is: What is the purpose for those components?

My leading theory on 1) is that it allows current flowing in the wrong direction (say the fan is spun backwards) to somehow dissipate or one way or another ensure that the ground wire between the fan and MOSFET isn't building up a charge. Unclear on this and would appreciate a better breakdown if correct.

On 2), maybe a voltage divider to drive the MOSFET at a lower voltage? It's confusing because I thought that the point of a FET was to not sink current to ground but maybe I have that wrong. The 10K resistor I believe exists to drive the pin from floating to ground when it is disconnected ensuring that the MOSFET drains. That part makes sense.

[image]

Comment: Your orthodox circuit will switch the DC fan on or off you dont want a potential divider because small fets can be driven from the MCU logic voltage.

Comment: For the [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode), do the answers in [What is the point of the diode in parallel to the fan here?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/564594/what-is-the-point-of-the-diode-in-parallel-to-the-fan-here) and [Does a fan need a flyback diode?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313045/does-a-fan-need-a-flyback-diode) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diode is a flyback diode. The fan motor is an inductive load, which means that it will generate a voltage across itself opposite to the motor current flow when turned off abruptly. The diode provides a path for current to flow and sink the flyback voltage, protecting the MOSFET from a potentially high voltage spike that can be induced by the stopping motor.

R24 is likely a simple pulldown resistor which makes sure the MOSFET is off during startup. R42 is a gate resistor which slows down the switching of the MOSFET and reduces transient currents, which can generate EM interference if too high (such as a case with a power MOSFET with a high gate capacitance)

Comment: Thank you, looks like I learned two new concepts today.